# How to convert nsstring in to encryption format that also supported in php?

Tags: iphone, encryption, nsstring, cryptography

I want to convert an `NSString` into some encryption format and then decrypt it also, but the problem is that I am using php web service and I also care that the method I am using is supported in.

So I want some mehod that is supported or compatible between both objective-c and php. My string is on a server, so i want to convert them.

Thanks in advance:-)

Answer (score 1):

[RNCryptor github link](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor)

I have had good success with this library, you just call `encryptData:` with whatever options you want, and then `decryptData` to get it back later. See the github page for details, as well as RNCryptor.h and .m if you want to actually see what's happening.